# How to use one of the icons from a svg file in the HTML?

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

I have an svg file containing two icons. Here is the code of svg:

```
<svg width="108" height="64" viewBox="0 0 108 64" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M41 32C41 27.0312 36.9688 23 32 23C27.0312 23 23 27.0312 23 32C23 36.9688 27.0312 41 32 41C36.9688 41 41 36.9688 41 32Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
<path d="M32 28.25V35.75M35.75 32H28.25" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path d="M76 22.25C70.6239 22.25 66.25 26.6239 66.25 32C66.25 37.3761 70.6239 41.75 76 41.75C81.3761 41.75 85.75 37.3761 85.75 32C85.75 26.6239 81.3761 22.25 76 22.25ZM79.75 32.75H76.75V35.75C76.75 35.9489 76.671 36.1397 76.5303 36.2803C76.3897 36.421 76.1989 36.5 76 36.5C75.8011 36.5 75.6103 36.421 75.4697 36.2803C75.329 36.1397 75.25 35.9489 75.25 35.75V32.75H72.25C72.0511 32.75 71.8603 32.671 71.7197 32.5303C71.579 32.3897 71.5 32.1989 71.5 32C71.5 31.8011 71.579 31.6103 71.7197 31.4697C71.8603 31.329 72.0511 31.25 72.25 31.25H75.25V28.25C75.25 28.0511 75.329 27.8603 75.4697 27.7197C75.6103 27.579 75.8011 27.5 76 27.5C76.1989 27.5 76.3897 27.579 76.5303 27.7197C76.671 27.8603 76.75 28.0511 76.75 28.25V31.25H79.75C79.9489 31.25 80.1397 31.329 80.2803 31.4697C80.421 31.6103 80.5 31.8011 80.5 32C80.5 32.1989 80.421 32.3897 80.2803 32.5303C80.1397 32.671 79.9489 32.75 79.75 32.75Z" fill="black"/>
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="107" height="63" rx="4.5" stroke="#9747FF" stroke-dasharray="10 5"/>
</svg>
```

I am trying to use one of the icons in this file, but the html **displays nothing** when I insert the svg file like this:

```
<svg>
    <use href="icons/circle.svg"></use>
</svg>
```

The whole image can be displayed by <img> tag. But can I do it by <svg> tag and select the specific icon I'd like to display?

Comment: did you try the simple way, <img src = "happy.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
<img src="Your SVG-File Path"/>
```

This will work

when not make sure that the path is correct